# Error modifying tabs on template

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to modify a tab on a template through the API but i get this error:

The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Tab not found in envelope.

Here is my PUT call:

```
"<tabs xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
            "<textTabs><text>" +
            "<name>year</name>" +
            "<value>15</value>" +
            "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
            "</text></textTabs>" +
            "</tabs>";
```

When I call the get for this:
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountID}/envelopes/{envelopeID}/recipients/1/tabs

I see the tab in the response.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you performing this update on a template, or an actual live/draft envelope that was created from a template?  Regardless, i'm fairly certain that you need to specify the TabID when modifying a pre-existing tab on a template: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20Tabs%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=modify%20tab

Comment: This if from an envelope created from a template. I updated the PUT call to include the tabID from the GET response. Still getting the error.